# Android Can't Remember My Files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file

I am writing a notepad app and I'm making a `create a password` screen pop up until you've created one, and then a `log in` screen will pop up from then on.

Here is some sample code:

```
File myFile = new File(getFilesDir() + "pass.txt");
if (!myFile.exists()) // if "pass.txt" DOESN'T exist, make them create a password
{ 
    try {

    // this writes the password to the "pass.txt" file 
    // which is the one that is checked to exist.
    // after it is written to, it should always exist.
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("pass.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(pass.getBytes());

    // this writes the security question to a different file.
    fos = openFileOutput("securityQ.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(secQ.getBytes());

    // this writes the security answer to a different file.
    fos = openFileOutput("securityAnswer.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(secAns.getBytes());

    fos.close();

} catch(Exception e) {}
```

^ That is in one method. Then, in another I do this:

```
try { // input the right password to the String data
    char[] inputBuffer = new char[1024];
    fIn = openFileInput("pass.txt");
    isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
    isr.read(inputBuffer);
    data = new String(inputBuffer);
    isr.close();
    fIn.close();
}catch(IOException e){}

if (password.getText().toString().equals(data)) // if password is right, log in.
{
    loggedin();
}
else // if the password entered is wrong, display the right one.
{
    TextView scr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);
    scr.setText("." + data + "."+'\n'+"." + password.getText().toString() + ".");
}
```

The problem is that the user can't log in even though the password is entered correctly and the display proves that.

The other problem is that whenever I run the app again, it goes to the create screen, which means that it is recognizes the file to NOT exist (even though I just wrote to it).

I've dealt with files this whole project and it can keep track of entered text so that when you press a button, it reads the file back to you. Even if you close it, it keeps track of what you input. For some reason though, the password thing doesn't work.

Here is an image of what happens (the first `.k.` is the data read from the `"pass.txt"` file and the second `.k.` is the user inputted `String` from the `EditText`):

[image]

**SOLUTION to the logging in problem:**

[String values look the same but don't ".equals()" each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929290/string-values-look-the-same-but-dont-equals-each-other)

Had to simply use the `.trim()` method on the password user input.

Comment: I think you should use SharedPreferences to save the password and user name, look this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: @Tobiel : i think he should only save username in preferences,saving critical info such as password will not be feasible as the preferences can be read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll pass on commenting about saving passwords in a file called "pass.txt", and just focus on the technical part.

```
File myFile = new File(getFilesDir() + "pass.txt");
```

`myFile` will never be a valid file. You don't have a separator `/` between the path and the file name. Since that will never be vaild, the next line will say it doesn't exist and go through the whole block.

You can easily fix this one of two ways:

```
File myFile = new File(getFilesDir() + "/pass.txt");
```

That simply adds the separator to the file name.

```
File myFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "pass.txt");
```

This is probably the better option, since it uses the explicit `path, file` constructor. Either one is fine, though.

Comment: For that I'd try logging `data` to see what it actually contains. If it contains the right value, you might want to check that `display` is the right field. `setText()` doesn't just not work.

Comment: I don't understand. You edited it to show that you're now writing to one file and reading from another(`pass.txt` and `passB.txt`). Have you actually logged the value of `data` as I suggested before? It doesn't matter what your file contains; if it's not being read in right, it won't equal anything you type. Also check for newlines, whitespace, etc.

Comment: I suppose that works. Well, if `data` is right, you need to check the value of `password.getText().toString()`. One of the two is not what you expect, or `equals()` would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use `context.openFileInput("pass.txt");` and catch if `FileNotFoundException` occurs, at which point you can "assume" the file actually doesn't exist.