# String values look the same but don't ".equals()" each other

Tags: android, string, file, chars

I'm making a log in screen. It doesn't work so I decided to display the password (saved to a file), and the inputted password to the screen for comparison.

```
// filePassword is the password inputted from the file as a String.
// password is the String value of the EditText on the screen.
if (password.equals(filePassword))
{
    logIn();
}
```

I compared `Strings` like this:

```
else 
{
    scr.setText("." + filePassword + "." + '\n' + "." + password + ".");
}
```

This was the `String` comparison:

[image]

I compared `chars` like this

```
else 
{
    char[] filePass = filePassword.toCharArray();
    char[] pass = password.toCharArray();
}
```

This was the `char` comparison:

[image]

The outputs for this `char array` change every time you press the button.

Obviously there is a difference in the `char arrays`. I have no idea why. Could it be something to do with the way I've worked with the files? Probably not, considering it didn't happen anywhere else in my project.

Is there any way to fix this comparison? Using the `.toString()` method on both values doesn't work.

**____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________**

### Solution

```
if (password.equals(filePassword))
```

needs to be:

```
if (password.equals(filePassword.trim()))
```

The `char array` comparisons will always be different. The way to compare them is this:

```
import java.util.Arrays; // add to top of class
scr.setText(Arrays.toString(password.toCharArray()));  
scr.append(Arrays.toString(filePassword.toCharArray()));
```

Comment: can you please tell me what you want to do actually ?

Comment: The chars you are seeing are different because that printed string `[C@????` is the address of the array, not the contents. To print the contents of an array use `Arrays.toString(...)`.

Comment: Can you post the code that actually does the comparison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could there be an extra character in any of the strings? Maybe a carriage return `\r`? You could use `length()` on both, or `trim()`, and compare afterwards. Or try:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(password.toCharArray()));  
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(filePassword.toCharArray()));
```

Comment: that's why I added periods to each ends of the `Strings`. There shouldn't be any leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: There still could be. Try the `Arrays.toString(password.toCharArray())` I just added to the answer.

Comment: `input pass` is `[k]` and `file pass` is `[k, , , , , etc.]`. The `.trim()` worked. I have no idea why the `file input` was like that but was not displayed as such when displayed as a `String`, but I don't care; you're a genius.